# Iterating three tangent circles using Malfatti Circles

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

First, construct three tangent circles (blue circles), then construct the triangle joining their centers. Then construct three [Malfatti Circles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MalfattiCircles.html) for this triangle (green circles). Go on.

[image]

What I'm asking is this - it appears that the radii of the green circles are closer together, than the radii of the blue cirlces. I.e., if the radius of a blue circle is $R_k$ and the green circle $r_k$, then we have:

$$\frac{\max{R_k}}{\min{R_k}} \geq \frac{\max{r_k}}{\min{r_k}},~~~k=1,2,3$$

Where equality is supposed to be only for three equal cirlces.

> Is this true for any initial three cirlces? Does it mean, that this iteration will have three equal cirlces as a limit?

I know that there are formulas for the radii of the Malfatti Circles, but they are very complicated and I would appreciate it if someone gives me a quick answer. If not, I will have to do a lengthy calculation.